# Azure storage blob library download blob to local machine

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-storage-files

I am following this tutorial and trying to see how I can download the blob file on my local machine

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser#prerequisites

And a little bit from here
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob#download-a-blob-and-convert-it-to-a-string-browsers

This is a web app using JavaScript.

The following lines of code work well and I can see the content of the file in console.log
Instead of seeing it in console.log, I want the user to be able to download the file to their local machine. So maybe giving a path  or something.

I have comment the code that I need help with. It runs but does nothing. I am not seeing a message to download to local.

```
const downloadFiles = async () => {
  

    if (fileList.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
        //reportStatus("downloading files...");
        for (const option of fileList.selectedOptions) {
            console.log("option.text", option.text);
            
            try {
                const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(option.text);
                console.log("BlobClient",blobClient)
                
                // Hoping this line of code would do the trick
                var blobResponse = await blobClient.downloadToFile(option.text);
                //////

                const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
                console.log("downloadBlockBlobResponse", downloadBlockBlobResponse);
               const downloaded = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
               console.log("Downloaded blob to string content", downloaded);

                // [Browsers only] A helper method used to convert a browser Blob into string.
                async function blobToString(blob) {
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fileReader.onloadend = (ev) => {
                    resolve(ev.target.result);
                };
                fileReader.onerror = reject;
                fileReader.readAsText(blob);
                });
              }

              // [Node.js only] A helper method used to read a Node.js readable stream into a Buffer
                async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const chunks = [];
                    readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
                        chunks.push(data instanceof Buffer ? data : Buffer.from(data));
                    });
                    readableStream.on("end", () => {
                        resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
                    });
                    readableStream.on("error", reject);
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                reportStatus(error.message);
            }
        }
        reportStatus("Done.");
        listFiles();
    } else {
        reportStatus("No files selected.");
    }

/*
    //const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    //console.log("containerClient", containerClient);
    const blobName =  // "MyTest1.csv";
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
  console.log("blobClient", blobClient);
    try {
        const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
        console.log("downloadBlockBlobResponse", downloadBlockBlobResponse);
        const downloaded = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
        console.log("Downloaded blob content", downloaded);
      
        // [Browsers only] A helper method used to convert a browser Blob into string.
        async function blobToString(blob) {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fileReader.onloadend = (ev) => {
              resolve(ev.target.result);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsText(blob);
          });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        reportStatus(error.message);
    }
    */
};
```

Comment: Hi Frank, this helped a bunch. Thanks a million. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `downloadToFile` method only available in `node.js` runtime, so you cannot use it to download files to local, you can refer to [downloadToFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#downloadToFile_string__number__number__BlobDownloadOptions_).

[image]

You can try the following methods to download files：

```
const downloadFiles = async () => {
    if (fileList.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
        reportStatus("downloading files...");
        for (const option of fileList.selectedOptions) {
            console.log("option.text", option.text);
            
            try {
                const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(option.text);
                console.log("BlobClient",blobClient);

                const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
                const url =window.URL.createObjectURL(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
                
                downloadURI(url,option.text)
                console.log("Downloaded blob to string content", url);
            }
            catch (error) {
                reportStatus(error.message);
            }
        }
        reportStatus("Done.");
        listFiles();
    } else {
        reportStatus("No files selected.");
    }
};

downloadButton.addEventListener("click", downloadFiles);

function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
};
```